# MATLAB Doesn't Start in Linux

Tags: matlab, startup

I have installed MATLAB in Ubuntu 14.04 and the installation was successful. However, when typing MATLAB in the command line or clicking on the MATLAB application, in both cases the logo of MATLAB come up but MATLAB never starts and the logo remain on the screen.

Can I know where the problem is and how I can solve it ?

Comment: Have you tried ```matlab -nodisplay```? Which Matlab version? 32- vs 64 bit?

Comment: 64 bit matlab under Ubuntu 64 bit. I noticed I receive this error while trying `matlab -nodisplay`: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mathworks.services.settings.SettingValidationException: IMsgIDException for "matlab.workingfolder.LastFolderPath": Internal

The error is long.

Comment: However, it works. The error reported is the internal error of MATLAB and by ctrl+c  can use the matlab nodisplay version.

Comment: The problem is solved by using `sudo matlab` which is kind of strange why there is a need for this each time. Why there is need for superpower privilege ... ?

Comment: @Yas watch with `sudo matlab`, running GUIs with `sudo` can mess with your file ownerships. Use `gksu` when you're running a program with a GUI (like MATLAB). Odds are that during installation some root-specific files were set, and your regular user doesn't have permission to modify those when MATLAB starts.

Comment: Thanks, I installed gsku it calls matlab evey looks fine but the GUI never comes up and for me it is important to work with the GUI. Do you have other solutions in mind?

Comment: I don't know if you found an answer for this, but with fedora 28+ you need to install 'libnsl'.